# Cannot run an executable from Mono C# compiler in WINDOWS XP without .net framework

Tags: c#, windows, mono, windows-xp

I have gone to this link http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aWindows
I can do successfully Run an executable from Mono C# compiler in WINDOWS 7 / Windows that have .net framework. But when I want to RUN this executable in windows XP without .net framework is failed, some errors appear.
I am using mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe installer for windows XP.
How to get success to run this Executable in windows XP without .net framework ?

Comment: `mono yourexecutable.exe` at Mono command prompt.

Comment: Thanks Lex li, I got the answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure use stable version of mono-2.10.9-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0 for windows XP
- Dont use version 3 for this moment: Bug 10302 - Fatal error in System.Windows.Forms.Control constructor in 3.0.3 https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10302

Optional: Compile the project using stable version of mono-2.10.9 as well: follow this link http://nbevans.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/targeting-mono-in-visual-studio-2012/